# Spring boot: Permit specific services to avoid security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have multiple services. All of them use jwt for authorization. However when my services communicate between each other I don't want them to authenticate. When Client sends a request to serviceA and serviceA needs data from serviceB it is enough for me that serviceA validates the token (also the other way around when the client sends a request to serviceB). I am using eureka as registry and openfeign to communicate between the services.
Right now I always get a 401 response like this:

```
feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: [401] during [GET] to [http://userservice/eschuler]
```

To be more specific my authservice want to send a request to the userservice.

```
@FeignClient(name = "userservice")
public interface UserClient {
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<UserAccount> getUserById(@PathVariable String id);
}
```

This is the UserController containing the getUserById Method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/kimoji/rest/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;
    private final JwtTokenService jwtTokenService;

    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder encoder, JwtTokenService jwtTokenService) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.encoder = encoder;
        this.jwtTokenService = jwtTokenService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserAccount> getUserById(@PathVariable String id) {
        Optional<UserAccount> userAccount = userRepository.findById(id);
        return userAccount.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }


 ...
    
}
```

This is the WebSecurityConfig from my userservice:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/kimoji/rest/users/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use an API gateway? Netflix Zuul or something similar?

Comment: Yes I do use spring cloud gateway

Comment: Well, the communication from the outside happens only through the API gateway and the microservices are not touched directly. Is there an option for you to leave them unsecured so they can talk to each other freely and secure only the communication between the outer environment and the API gateway?

Comment: You mean that I add the authorization to the gateway?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd start here: https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway. I'd go with this way, however, somebody else might post an actual answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It might be the prettier solution. I will take a closer look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of avoiding security, what you want to do is always pass a token.

If the Service A is calling Service B and the request is originated from an external Client. Just pass the same token to Service B that originated from the Client to Service A.

If Service A is initiating the call (some sort of maintenance job) then use the Client Credentials flow to go to your Identity Provider and create a token for Service A to pass to Service B.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for your answer! I will take a look on how to pass a token with FeignClient. In general what do you think about relocating the auth to the gateway just like Nikolas recommended? So that only the gateway authorizing requests and the services behind the gateway don't need authorize any request.

Comment: Yes, that is the other way to do it; as long as your network is set up correctly and doesn't have any holes in it. :)  To pass the token, you just need to get the token from the SpringSecurity ContextHolder and then add a Header on your new call. `Authorization: "bearer eyJhbGciO...."`

Comment: Just remember if you don't pass the token to Service B, you won't be able to tell who the original actor is, so if you are doing any auditing of your transactions, you won't know the user.

Comment: https://medium.com/@IlyasKeser/feignclient-interceptor-for-bearer-token-oauth-f45997673a1

Comment: @k1m0j  if that is the correct answer, can you mark it as correct?

Comment: I am trying it out now. Do you have by chance an idea how an RequestInterceptor could look like when working with jwt.io. The link u shared is for OAuth. Cant quite figure out how to adapt this.

Comment: Okay now one Problem is when I want to create a new JWT Token. The gateway is sending the request to my AuthService. The Authservice then calls the UserRestService to check if the User does exist to create the token. But the UserRestService needs an authentication for accessing the getUserById Method which I can't provide since the token has not been created yet. Maybe thats just bad design by me I am not sure. I am new to this :)

Comment: Doesn't the AuthService, at a minimum, have a table of usernames and passwords?  It should know it that user exists by the presence of the username.

Comment: No the only service which keeps user informations is the UserService its self.

Comment: Could be a design issue there. Normally your auth service, will contain at least the data it needs to complete the login as a self contained transaction.  Se the database per service pattern: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html

Comment: But isn't that what I am trying to do. My User Rest Service has access to the UserAccount database. So following the database per service pattern my Auth Service should not have any access to the UserAccount Database. Or do you mean that its bad design to separate both Auth and User in two different services.